# change the color of the button and save the information

Tags: flutter, button, light

we have 9 buttons (1 is the lowest the main button and 8 other buttons), and 8 lights (buttons that their color change randonly while pressing the main button). (demonstrated in the picture below).
we want the player to press the button that match the light that turned.
how we can change the light color according to the random choice and understand which light turned, save this information and check if the button pressed by the player is the correct one

we tried to used the key factor of the button Widget but it didnt work

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsLDR.png)

Comment: Please provide a code snippet of what you have achieved so far.

Comment: still don't understand what you're trying. Can you give few examples?

Answer (score 0):

if you're using BLoC, you could just save the main light into a variable, and then when user tap the other 8 button you can just compare it.

ex :
main button -> on init -> bloc.setColor(Color color) -> save the current color on variable on BLoC

the other 8 button -> on tap -> bloc.userAnswers(Color color) -> compare -> if true return correct if false return wrong (depend on what you want)

I hope this is what you mean.